# Access substring of class constant with array index operator

Tags: php, arrays, string, operators, constants

```
class Foo {
 const BAR = 'Hello';
}

echo Foo::BAR; //Works
echo Foo::BAR[0]; //Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';'
```

I've found a way around this by using `substr`, but I'm curious to know why this doesn't work as it is.

PHP 5.3.3 by the way.

Comment: Note that you may be able to do what you need to do like this:  `$foo = Foo::BAR;  $foo = $foo[0];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that PHP considers class constants like "classic" constants (e.g. created with `define()`).

Therefore, they are [simply replaced by their values at runtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php), so `Foo::BAR[0]` would be interpreted by PHP as `'Hello'[0]` which is not a valid syntax (`$myVariable[0]` being allowed).